# ¿Como sumar determinadas partes de una Matriz? (Filas y columnas)

Tags: python

Mi código como ejemplo:

```
Matriz = []
cont = 1
for fila in range(4):
    Matriz.append([])
    for columna in range(6):
        Matriz[fila].append(columna)
        Matriz[fila][columna] = cont
        cont = cont + 1
```

Salida:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 
[7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12], 
[13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18], 
[19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24]]
```

La pregunta es... si quisiera sumar la fila 1 y la fila 3, como lo haria? Y seria el mismo procedimiento que sumando las columnas, no?

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿Necesitas sumar fila 1 y fila 3 y regresar un solo número (114)?¿O sumar elemento por elemento ([14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24])?¿Cuál sería el resultado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agregando un poco de código a tu código
Aca estamos insertando elementos a través de cont. que empezara desde
1 hasta 24.

```
Matriz = []
cont = 1
for fila in range(4):
    Matriz.append([])
    for columna in range(6):
        Matriz[fila].append(columna)
        Matriz[fila][columna] = cont
        cont = cont + 1
print(Matriz)
```

Adicione lo siguiente:
Declare una variable fila1 donde almacenare la fila que quiero sumar sus elementos.
Después inicialice una variable suma donde se almacenara la suma respectiva.

```
fila1 = int(input("Ingrese la fila a sumar: "))
suma = 0
```

Después Recorremos entre filas y columnas la matriz..

```
for fila in range(4):
    for columna in range(6):
        if(fila==(fila1-1)):
            print(Matriz[fila][columna])
            suma=suma+Matriz[fila][columna]
print(suma)
```

Donde si fila iterada en mi primer for es igual a (fila1-1 -> porque le pongo menos 1, porque si yo ingreso 1 me va a leer la variable 0, ya que empezamos desde cero la matriz con respecto a la variable fila). si es igual entonces
que me calcule todo los elementos que estan en esa fila y despues sumarlos respectivamente y almacenarlo en la variable suma para después imprimirlo.

```
Ingrese la fila a sumar: 2
57
```

Answer (score 0):

En Python la vida es simple. Si tienes una matriz como

```
matriz = [
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
[7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12],
[13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18],
[19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24]]
```

y quieres sumar un par de filas, lo haces con comprensión de listas:

```
# Sumar por filas (primera + tercera)
print([x[0] + x[1] for x in zip(matriz[0], matriz[2])])
```

produce:

```
[14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24]
```

La función `zip` toma dos o más *iterables* (en este caso, filas de la columna) y va devolviendo tuplas que contienen un elemento de cada iterable. Así consigo obtener juntos los elementos correspondientes de ambas filas.

Teniendo los elementos, sólo queda sumarlos para producir la lista final.

La operación por columnas es similar:

```
# Sumar por columnas (segunda + tercera)
print([x[1] + x[2] for x in matriz])
```

produce:

```
[5, 17, 29, 41]
```

En este caso, el `for` devuelve filas, y con `x[1], x[2]` tomamos los elementos en columnas segunda y tercera para sumarlos.
Definimos una función que suma dos vectores de igual largo,`v1` y `v2`, retornando un tercer vector, donde cada elemento es la suma de los elementos correspondientes en `v1` y `v2`.

En ambos casos el resultado de la operación es una lista, a la que puedes aplicar las operaciones usuales de `min, max, sum,` etc.